# My Book Essential Edition : switch box

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a My Book Essential Edition 1To. Sadly I connected the wrong power cable and so a bad smell was coming from the box.

As it was out of support, I opend it thinking  I will plug it directly to my computer and backup the data.

I tried it but seems that there is hardware encryption of the drive. So I can't read any data.

The issue is the small piece of hardware which provides USB and power to the hard drive. This part just burn.

My question is : Can I bought a new My Book Essential Edition and switch the hard drive ? My aim is to get my data back.

FYI I tried many software to restore the data but it wasn't able to read anything. Looking on google didn't return anything.

Thanks !

Comment: Do you see at least the partition table?

Comment: hello, no I can't see partition table. I just bought the usb motherboard on ebay. I need to try it and see if it works !

Comment: If the internal USB adapter would not work then I am afraid the only way would be a cryptanalysis. The drive could be encrypted by a simple [XOR cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) which is extremely easy to break when you know some parts of the encrypted data (for example sectors containing zeroes). The beginning would be to visualize the data. See for example: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bin2bmp/ http://pleasefeedthegeek.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/converting-binaries-into-images/ For more advanced entropy visualisation: http://corte.si/posts/visualisation/entropy/